# How to maximize a unit (i.e. salary in this case) using dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

This is an interview question

> There is a series of days `D1, D2,...Dn` that you can choose to work. Each working `i`-th
>       day you are paid with a salary `Si`. If you work in day `Di`, then you could not work for
>       the following `Ni` days right after. Maximize your salary using DP.

Below is the solution I came up with:

Let OPT (i) denote the maximum salary at day Di. There are 2 possibilities that either I work on the ith day or not. My recurrence formula:
OPT (i) = max (OPT(i-Ni)+Si, OPT(i-1)

```
Maximize_salary(n)
Initialize my array M[i] = 0 for i <= 0
for i = 1 to n
  M[i] = max(M[i-Ni]+Si, M[i-1])
end for
return M[n]
```

Is my approach correct? I worry about the for loop interval since I'm using i-Ni. Do I need to initialize all values in array M up to Ni?

I think the complexity of my algorithm is O(n).

Comment: No, that's why you need to find a solution to maximize the total S you earn

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, although you could simply check if `M[k]` you trying to access exists and return 0 if it does not. Also if today is day `d`, and you have not worked for `r` days, the last day you could work was `d - r - 1`.

```
    def maximizeSalary(M, N, S, n):
        def getM(index):
            if index < 0: return 0 else: return M[index]

        for i = 0 to n - 1:
            M[i] = max(getM(i - N[i] - 1) + S[i], getM(i - 1))
```